# Updating a .txt file

Tags: file, coldfusion, cfml

I'm outputting the results of a query to file.txt in JSON. The file is updated every time I click on 'submit'(form) and depending on the variables it updates the query.

Right now the table only has about 20 records and will probably increase by 2/3 new records everyday.

Is there a better way to updating the file test.txt getting the results from a query?

**index.cfm**:

```
  <cfsavecontent variable="mytest"> 
    [
    <cfoutput query="getimeline"> 
    <cfif (getimeline.CurrentRow EQ getimeline.RecordCount)>
    {"title":"#name_time#","date":"#dateformat(date_time,"mmmm d, yyyy")#"}
    <cfelse>
    {"title":"#name_time#","date":"#dateformat(date_time,"mmmm d, yyyy")#"},
    </cfif>

    </cfoutput> 
    ]
    </cfsavecontent> 

    <cffile action="write" file="C:test.txt"  output="#mytest#">
```

**test.txt**:

```
[

{"title":"Advance pay Rollovers","date":"October 23, 2015"},

{"title":"New Card Ordering Process 1","date":"December 28, 2015"},

{"title":"about about","date":"February 5, 2016"}

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know sqat about [coldfusion](/questions/tagged/coldfusion), but it seems you could eliminate some duplication:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="mytest"> 
    [
    <cfoutput query="getimeline"> 
    {"title":"#name_time#","date":"#dateformat(date_time,"mmmm d, yyyy")#"}<cfif (getimeline.CurrentRow NEQ getimeline.RecordCount)>,</cfif>    
    </cfoutput> 
    ]
</cfsavecontent> 

<cffile action="write" file="C:test.txt"  output="#mytest#">
```

If you don't mind that the comma will get placed on the next line,
then you can use this more readable writing style:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="mytest"> 
    [
    <cfoutput query="getimeline"> 
    {"title":"#name_time#","date":"#dateformat(date_time,"mmmm d, yyyy")#"}
    <cfif (getimeline.CurrentRow NEQ getimeline.RecordCount)>,</cfif>    
    </cfoutput> 
    ]
</cfsavecontent> 

<cffile action="write" file="C:test.txt"  output="#mytest#">
```